# PHP combine array_sum and multiplication in foreach

Tags: php, foreach

how can I multiply the result of an `array_sum` in a `foreach` loop?

Example: I have product1 with a value of 10, product 2 with a value of 20. Each product is bought twice: I need to have (10 + 20)*2 = 60. I tried the following:

```
($number[$key]) * (array_sum($totprod[$key]))
```

but this is not working `(result = blank)`.

Thank you for your help

Here is my foreach ($number = quantity)

```
foreach ($number as $key => $value){     
   $total[$key] = array($product1[$key], $product2[$key]);      
   echo "<pre>Quantity " . $number[$key] . "Price product1 " . $product1[$key] . " Price product2 " . $product2[$key] . " = Total price " . $number[$key] * array_sum($total[$key]) . "</pre>";   
}
```

Comment: Maybe show some more code (where is your `foreach` loop?), explain the meaning of `$number[$key]` and `$totprod[$key]`?

Comment: I updated my question with the foreach, thanks

Comment: If you doint MATH in PHP, do always `()` around it  `($number[$key] * array_sum($total[$key]))`, else it can go very wrong.

Comment: Just a note: `result = blank` It can not be blank because you are printing text `<pre>Quantity`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that sum is the best approach here since
(10 + 20) * 2 = 2*10 + 2*20

You probably better just calculate totals for each products and sum all results as it would work in the general case (1 productX + 6productY).

Now generally speaking, dealing with money, you should avoid array_sum and all php native math operators as you could have some surprises like total VAT != sum of all product's VAT.
When dealing with money, or when precision must be controlled, use bcmath http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php

Comment: _dealing with money, you should avoid array_sum_ I disagree. There is no reason for this concern. Better take a look at your code which is dealing with money...BTW: your post is not answering OPs question, statements like _I don't think that sum is_ ... or _You probably better just calculate_ sound just like vague speculations.

Comment: I was just being kind by not stating final arguments, and it's hard to go more in depth with this few details. Now if you think base2/base10 conversion do not create problems when manipulating prices in PHP, sorry but you are wrong.